# Calculate initial values based on day-over-day's pct_change in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Let's say I have a **day over day growth rate data** as follows, in which the initial values are unknown to us:

```
           date  dod_change
0      2020-1-1    0.262713
1      2020-1-2    0.216778
2      2020-1-3    0.217069
3      2020-1-4    0.268117
4      2020-1-5    0.341397
..          ...         ...
660  2021-10-22    0.579067
661  2021-10-23    0.616211
662  2021-10-24    0.680849
663  2021-10-25    0.718568
664  2021-10-26    0.682004
```

Obviously, the logic of calculation of `dod_change` is `current_day_value/previous_day_value - 1`, ie., for `2020-1-1`'s `dod_change=0.262713` is calculate by the `(initial value of 2020-1-1)/(initial value of 2019-12-31) - 1`

Now I wonder if it's possible to write a function to calculate an **approximate daily year over year's growth rate** based on `dod_change`? For example, we could set the initial value for `2019-12-31` as `100`, then calculate each day's approximate initial value, then apply function below to get yoy data:

```
def calculate_daily_yoy(x):
    do = pd.DateOffset(years = 1)
    x_yoy = x.pct_change(freq = do)
    return pd.DataFrame(x_yoy, columns=x.columns)
```

But I dont't know how to write a function to calculate the initial value for each day, anyone could help? Sincere thanks.

To generate example data for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2015', periods = 720, freq = 'D'), 
                   'dod_change1': np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size = 720), 
                   'dod_change2': np.random.uniform(-0.1, 0.1, size = 720)})
print(df)
```

Out:

```
          date  dod_change1  dod_change2
0   2015-01-01     0.105978     0.046144
1   2015-01-02     0.233369    -0.042252
2   2015-01-03    -0.361053    -0.072793
3   2015-01-04    -0.187327    -0.070694
4   2015-01-05     0.497243     0.054125
..         ...          ...          ...
715 2016-12-16    -0.180490    -0.049211
716 2016-12-17    -0.349578     0.034892
717 2016-12-18     0.312242    -0.099226
718 2016-12-19    -0.153010     0.095887
719 2016-12-20    -0.347153    -0.036274

[720 rows x 3 columns]
```

**Reference:**

[Calculate value using previously-calculated value (from the same column) and value from another column in a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56317359/calculate-value-using-previously-calculated-value-from-the-same-column-and-val)

Comment: Unfortuantely not idea, sorry :(