# Filter rows without any NaNs and date is consecutive in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's I have a `df` in which date column is consecutive:

```
          date     a   b     c
0    2021-10-1   8.0  10  12.0
1    2021-10-2   NaN  16   NaN
2    2021-10-3   1.0  14   NaN
3    2021-10-4   2.0  15   NaN
4    2021-10-5   3.0  16   5.0
5    2021-10-6   4.0  17   6.0
6    2021-10-7   9.0  22  11.0
7    2021-10-8  10.0  23  12.0
8    2021-10-9  11.0  24  13.0
9   2021-10-10  12.0  25  14.0
10  2021-10-11  13.0  26   NaN
11  2021-10-12   NaN  27   NaN
12  2021-10-13   NaN  28   NaN
```

I would like to filter rows in which date is consecutive and at same time no `NaN` for columns `a`, `b` and `c`.

With `df.dropna(how='any')`, I get:

```
         date     a   b     c
0   2021-10-1   8.0  10  12.0
4   2021-10-5   3.0  16   5.0
5   2021-10-6   4.0  17   6.0
6   2021-10-7   9.0  22  11.0
7   2021-10-8  10.0  23  12.0
8   2021-10-9  11.0  24  13.0
9  2021-10-10  12.0  25  14.0
```

But I hope to drop the first row as well even it doesn't have any `NaN`, since its date is not consecutive with others:

```
         date     a   b     c
4   2021-10-5   3.0  16   5.0
5   2021-10-6   4.0  17   6.0
6   2021-10-7   9.0  22  11.0
7   2021-10-8  10.0  23  12.0
8   2021-10-9  11.0  24  13.0
9  2021-10-10  12.0  25  14.0
```

How could I achieve that in Pandas? Thanks.

Comment: So you only want to keep non-nan rows if there are more than one in a block?

Comment: Yes, when two condition was met: 1. date column's content is consecutive, 2. no `NaN`s in all other 3 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test consecutive values by [`Series.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html), compare for `1` and for all values if not missing:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df[df["date"].diff().dt.days.eq(1) & df.notna().all(axis=1)]

print (df)
        date     a   b     c
4 2021-10-05   3.0  16   5.0
5 2021-10-06   4.0  17   6.0
6 2021-10-07   9.0  22  11.0
7 2021-10-08  10.0  23  12.0
8 2021-10-09  11.0  24  13.0
9 2021-10-10  12.0  25  14.0
```

If there is `DatetimeIndex`:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

df = df.set_index('date')

df = df[df.index.to_series().diff().dt.days.eq(1) & df.notna().all(axis=1)]
print (df)
               a   b     c
date                      
2021-10-05   3.0  16   5.0
2021-10-06   4.0  17   6.0
2021-10-07   9.0  22  11.0
2021-10-08  10.0  23  12.0
2021-10-09  11.0  24  13.0
2021-10-10  12.0  25  14.0
```

Comment: Thanks, if `date` column is `index` of `df`, so I should use `df[df.index.diff().dt.days.eq(1) & df.notna().all(axis=1)]`, right?

Comment: @ahbon - yes, you are close, but because `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'` need `df[df.index.to_series().diff().dt.days.eq(1) & df.notna().all(axis=1)]`

Comment: Thanks, do you mind have a look regarding this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69737407/calculate-initial-values-based-on-day-over-days-pct-change-in-python

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

```
df[df["date"].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta("1 day"))].dropna()
```

**explanation**

This calculates the difference between consecutive elements in the `date1 column

```
df["date"].diff()
```

This compares the differences to 1 day, and produces a series of True/False values

```
df["date"].diff().eq(pd.Timedelta("1 day"))
```

We can use that to filter to remove any row which does not have the following day in the data.

The last step is to call `.dropna` which removes any row which contains a `NaN` value

Comment: Do u mind add some explanations? Thanks.

Comment: updated for you

Comment: In real data, date column is index, so I get an error `AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'diff'`, when I use `df[df.index.diff().eq(pd.Timedelta("1 day"))].dropna()`

Comment: In that case use `df.index.to_series().diff()`